# Minimize Degradation While Meeting Output

Tags: matrices, optimization, algorithms, maxima-minima

I'm looking to optimize life on some components in a system. I have 3 components that work in parallel to meet one defined total output number. Each component has a variable output capability with an associated degradation value that follows a known curve. The curve is different for each component.

My question is, given a total output value, how do I determine how to split the output between the 3 components to minimize the overall sum of the associated degradation?

In my mind I have a 2D array for each component where the output is in row 1 and its associated degradation is below in row 2. Being able to pick only one pair of values from each array, I need the sum of the row 1 picks to meet a given value while minimizing the sum of the associated row 2 values.

Initial searches brought up the knapsack problem, but I don't know how to incorporate being able to pick only one pair of values from each array. I also came across the assignment problem, but having to meet the total output constraint while minimizing degradation stumped me. Any advice on how to set up this problem and methods to solve is greatly appreciated.

I thank you all in advance. Please excuse any improper use of terms/ideas. It has been a while since I've had to use this type of knowledge and I am in the process of dusting off the memory banks.